# Flipsideview strange behaviour

Tags: iphone, ios4, xcode4, flipside

I am having a strange problem with a simple test app I am writing for iPhone. I have a view with a flip side view. Now suddenly this view has the title two times high. In the IB (I am using xcode 4) this is how it is looking

[Picture of the IB](http://tinypic.com/r/2b5n4k/7)

In the end I get a two times higher title bar. Anyone ideas?

Thanks in advance,
Umberto

Comment: please include your image inline with your question, rather that only providing a link. Click help to learn how.

Comment: Let me check. Next time will do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The navigation item seems to have its `prompt` set. You will have to set it to `nil`.

```
self.navigationItem.prompt = nil;
```

or if you've access to the navigation bar,

```
navigationBar.navigationItem.prompt = nil;
```

Comment: I tried but it didn't help actually... and sorry for the late reply, was out for the weekend...

Comment: BUt you are right, adding a value for the prompt fill the black space above the title, but setting to nil does not remove the space.

Comment: Well if I try setting the prompt and then remove it, it doesn't adjust correctly. Your best bet would be to delete the navigation bar and add it again. And this seems to be a bug. You should file it.

Comment: Ok. The navigation bar was added automatically by IB when I created a small test app. Thanks for the feedback.